# Why don't I get the return of my function?

Tags: shell, return

In an inline shell, I type `echo $(max 15 2)` but don't get any answer?

Why is it so?

Code:

```
function max {
  if [ "$1" -eq "$2" ]
  then
    return $1
  else
    if [ "$1" -gt "$2" ]
    then
      return $1
    else
      return $2
    fi
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments :

- Replace return with echo and your code works fine. - Blender
- The `$(...)` syntax is specifically designed to give you the output of a command, even if that command happens to be a function call. return in a function is similar to exit for the script as a whole; it sets its status, which is an integer in the range 0 to 255. (This is quite different from other languages you might be used to, where return is used to return a value from a function.) – Keith Thompson
- Bash functions are not like functions in other languages. They behave the same as any other command: they can take command line arguments, read from standard input, write to standard output and standard error, and return with an exit status. They don't--strictly speaking--return a computed value. – chepner

Answer (score 3):

Replace `return` with `echo` and your code works fine.

Comment: Indeed, I remarked that but isn't it strange ? I would say that the role of `return` is to return a value, and the role of `echo` is to print a value.

Comment: Type in `man return` into your shell and read the manpage. `return` is for returning status codes.

Comment: So, the return of a function is with `echo` ?

Comment: More or less: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236871/how-to-return-a-string-value-from-a-bash-function

Comment: The `$(...)` syntax is specifically designed to give you the *output* of a command, even if that command happens to be a function call. `return` in a function is similar to `exit` for the script as a whole; it sets its status, which is an integer in the range 0 to 255. (This is quite different from other languages you might be used to, where `return` is used to return a value from a function.)

Comment: Bash functions are not like functions in other languages. They behave the same as any other command: they can take command line arguments, read from standard input, write to standard output and standard error, and return with an exit status. They don't--strictly speaking--return a computed value.

Comment: @chepner Functions absolutely do return a value.  The value they return is assigned to `$?` and is used to determine if the function succeeded or failed.

Comment: I'm trying to draw a distinction between exit status and a value computed by the function. You wouldn't typically define an add function as `add () { return $(( $1 + $2 )); }`.