# Bash: Return a string from bash function

Tags: linux, bash

I need a bash function to return a dynamically constructed string to returned to the caller space.
i.e,

```
makeName()
{
    echo "Enter Ext: "
    read ext
    return "$fileName.$1.$ext.log"
}


echo -n "Enter fileName:"
read fileName

name1=makeName "type1"
name2=makfName "type2"
```

So I can get two different filenames with same base file name.
I tries doing like this,

```
# echo $(makeName "type1")
```

But this code is struck somewhere with out any reason or error. I expect it to accept some kind of I/O with that proc also. That is not happening.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `return` statement used by `bash` is used to return a numeric value as a status code to be retrieved through `$?` by the calling function. You can not return a string. See also

- [Returning Values from Bash Functions](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions)
- [How to return a string value from a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236871/how-to-return-a-string-value-from-a-bash-function)

You can either use a special global variable as proposed by @konsolebox, or `echo` the return value inside your function, and use command substitution when calling the function:

```
makeName()
{
    echo "$fileName.$1.log"
}


echo -n "Enter fileName:"
read fileName

name1=$(makeName "type1")
name2=$(makeName "type2")

echo $name1
echo $name2
```

**[UPDATE]**

The updated question shows that you intend to read yet another value inside the `makeName` function, while the function also intends to `echo` some prompt for the user. So the command substitution approach will not work in that case - you need to use a global variable, like

```
makeName() {
    echo -n "Enter Ext: "
    read ext

    __="$fileName.$1.$ext.log"
}


echo -n "Enter fileName:"
read fileName

makeName "type1" ; name1=${__}
makeName "type2" ; name2=${__}

echo $name1
echo $name2
```

```
$ ./sample.sh 
Enter fileName:filename
Enter Ext: ext1
Enter Ext: ext2
filename.type1.ext1.log
filename.type2.ext2.log
```

Yet better, for cleaner code and to avoid using global variables inside your function, you could use the approach described at [Returning Values from Bash Functions](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions) and **pass the name of the return variable as parameter**, and ideally also pass the `fileName` as parameter:

```
makeName() {
    local  __type=$1
    local  __fileName=$2
    local  __resultvar=$3
    local ext
    local myresult

    echo -n "Enter Ext: "
    read ext
    myresult="$__fileName.$__type.$ext.log"

    eval $__resultvar="'$myresult'"
}

echo -n "Enter fileName:"
read fileName

makeName "type1" $fileName theResult ; name1=${theResult}
makeName "type2" $fileName theResult ; name2=${theResult}
echo $myresult

echo $name1
echo $name2
```

**Side Note**: See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead) for a discussion why `eval` should be avoided. When using bash version 3.1 or higher, you can use `printf` instead of `eval`:

```
...
printf -v "$__resultvar" '%s' "$myresult"
...
```

And, finally, with bash 4.3 or higher, we can assign the **nameref** attribute to a variable using `declare -n`, so that the variable is effectively a **reference** to another variable:

```
...
declare -n myresult=$3

myresult="$__fileName.$__type.$ext.log"
...
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, I have updated my question.

Comment: See my updated answer - essentially, you have misused `return`, and you also need to use the approach proposed by @konsolebox when your function intends to print output to stdout (other than the return value)

Comment: `theResult` is still a global variable; you've just taken a more complicated (and more dangerous, using `eval`) path to set it.

Comment: @chepner Yes, but it is only used in the global scope, not within the function. So the function is well encapsulated - proper encapsulation *is* usually more complicated ;) Anyway, I think that each of the approaches has pro's and con's and you still need to decide wisely which one to use in a specific scenario ...

Comment: Typically, encapsulation means that local variables are not accessed globally, rather than local variables are *only* used globally.

Comment: Ok since my idea is already included here, I'll give another tip: Instead of using `eval`, since the value returned is an ordinary value, and not an array, you can just use `printf`: `printf -v "$__resultvar" '%s' "$myresult"`. You need Bash 3.1.

Comment: Also, starting Bash 4.3, we can already use the most elegant solution which is `declare -n`.

Comment: @konsolebox `printf` works perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

Better way is to pick a general variable you could always use. Example:

```
makeName() {
    __="$fileName.$1.log"
}    

echo -n "Enter fileName:"
read fileName

makeName "type1"
name1=$__
makeName "type2"
name2=$__

echo "$name1"
echo "$name2"
```

Summoning subshells just to get a value from a function is really inefficient and slow.

Comment: +1 good point on the sub shell - I'd probably still prefer sub shells over global variables ;-), but your approach is definitely faster (looping the two `makeName` calls 1000 times takes less than 100ms, while the sub shell based solution takes almost 2 seconds).

Comment: cryptic nature of bash never ceases to amaze me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `return` with `echo`:

```
makeName()
{
    echo "Enter Ext: " >&2
    read ext
    echo "$fileName.$1.$ext.log"
}
```

Comment: That will end up with `Enter Ext: ` being part of the result ...

Comment: Oops. The prompt should be printed to standard error instead, either with `echo "Enter Ext: " >&2`, or by using the `-p` option available to `bash`'s implementation of `read` to display the prompt instead (`read -p "Enter Ext: " ext`).

Comment: ... and, you still need to use command substitution when calling `makeName` (which OP does not properly do, and which leads to the discussion we just had with @konsolebox ;-) )