# returning values from functions in bash

Tags: bash

I have a program on bash which calculates n'th number of Fibonacci seq. But keep getting an error `expr: syntax error`. As I understand this is because I return something from function in wrong way, but I dont understand how to make it right. Here is my code:

```
fib() {
    if (( $1 < 2 ))
    then
        return 1
    fi

    c=$(fib `expr $1 - 1`)
    b=$(fib `expr $1 - 2`)

    echo "$b $c" 
    #Here I have a blank line in output
    #So I thought may be the problem is about returning/reception values?

    return `expr $c + $b`
}
```

Comment: From [Returning Values from Bash Functions](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions): _"Bash functions, unlike functions in most programming languages do not allow you to return a value to the caller"_. Just assign a value and then check it. Otherwise, `echo` something and catch it doing `myvar=$(fib)`.

Comment: Also relevant: [How to Return a String Value from a Bash Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236871/how-to-return-a-string-value-from-a-bash-function?rq=1)

Comment: @fedorqui thanks a lot for this article! I understood whats going on)