# Execute shell function in variable

Tags: shell

I don't understand why my shell script doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/sh

getProjectsNames() {
   list=`ls -a`
   return $list
}

projectsNames=`getProjectsNames`
echo $projectsNames
```

This code is returning error:

> script.sh: 6: return: Illegal number: .

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `projectsNames=$(getProjectsNames)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unix shells, the `return` statement can only return **a number** that's eligible to be the exit code of a program. In most Linux and Unix systems, it's between 0 and 255.

If you want to pass a string, use stdout and output capturing:

```
#!/bin/sh

getProjectsNames() {
    list=`ls -a`
    echo "$list"
}

projectsNames=$(getProjectsNames)
```

Note the change from `return $list` to `echo "$list"`.

Answer (score 0):

Its because `return` expects a ***numerical value***, see from manual `return [n] : Causes a function to exit with the return value specified by n`

so if you want to capture something which returns from function, use `echo`, for example,

```
    #!/bin/sh

    getProjectsNames() {
        list=$(ls -a)
        echo "$list"
    }

    projectsNames=$(getProjectsNames)
    echo $projectsNames
```

see more here in this link, [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236871/how-to-return-a-string-value-from-a-bash-function)