# How to return file path instead of file contents in a bash function?

Tags: bash

I have a bash function within a sub shell that downloads a file from an s3 bucket and stores it within a json file:

```
download_file(){(
  fileName="$(mktemp)__trigger.json"
  aws_response="$(aws s3api get-object --version-id $VERSION_ID --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key=$OBJECT_NAME $fileName | jq -cj)"
  if [[ -s "$fileName" ]]; then
      log_error "Unable to download file!"
      return 1
  fi
  log_info "[success] downloaded file"
  echo -n "$fileName"
);}
```

However, when I call this function from my main script and then echo out the return value, it returns the contents of the file rather than the path to the file:

```
downloadedFileName="$(download_file)"

echo "$downloadedFileName"
```

I am still a novice in bash and am looking for a way to alter this code to return the path of the temporary file that I downloaded rather than the contents of the file when I echo it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What part of your function do you think stores the downloaded content in the file?

Comment: The ```s3api get-object``` [should store it within](https://www.gcptutorials.com/post/how-to-download-an-object-from-amazon-s3-using-aws-cli) ```$fileName``` I believe.

Comment: Ahh -- rereading, I see the filename being passed as a parameter. Missed that on the first pass.

Comment: I agree, it should behave as described. The jq call isn't doing anything because the data isn't being written to stdout and so isn't going through the pipeline, but that's relatively inconsequential.

Comment: Have you considered using `set -x` to trace your script? That way you can see exactly which output each individual line generates.

Comment: bash functions - despite of their name - don't really **return** anything. They can produce standard output and standard error, and set an 8-bit-return code, and that's it basically. You are catching standard output of your function, and we don't know what `log_error` and `log_info` is producing.  These are the only candidates (besides `echo`) which may effect the standard output. Consider as alternative passing to your function the name of a bash variable, which is going to receive the file name to be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [How to return a string value from a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236871/how-to-return-a-string-value-from-a-bash-function) for other suggestions on how to tackle.  The easiest way to handle this is just use `fileName` somewhere else in your script.  It will maintain the filename value that you want.