# How can I assign the output of a function *with parameters* to a variable using bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Similar to [How can I assign the output of a function to a variable using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809899/how-can-i-assign-the-output-of-a-function-to-a-variable-using-bash), but slightly different.

If I have a function like this:

```
function scan {
  echo "output"
}
```

...I can easily assign this to a variable like this:

```
VAR=$(scan)
```

Now, what if my function takes one or more parameters, how can I pass them to the function using the "shell expansion" syntax? E.g. this:

```
function greet {
  echo "Hello, $1"
}

# Does not work
VAR=$(greet("John Doe"))
```

The above produces an error like this with my bash (version `5.0.3(1)-release`):

```
$ ./foo.sh 
./foo.sh: command substitution: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `"John Doe"'
./foo.sh: command substitution: line 8: `greet("John Doe"))'
```

Answer (score 1):

in this code :

```
function greet {
  echo "Hello, $1"
}

# Does not work
VAR=$(greet("John Doe"))
```

the error is the parenthesis passing parameters.
try to do this:

```
function greet {
  echo "Hello, $1"
}

# works
VAR=$(greet "John Doe")
```

it should work.

Explanation: when you use the $ an the parenthesis you have to write inside the parenthesis command as in a shell so the parameters are passed without parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks. I already documented this (at the same time as writing the question) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59388263/227779 :-)

Comment: Why would I upvote it when it mostly just duplicates my answer which was written before? I discovered the answer to my question while writing it, but decided to write down the answer Q&A-style. Thanks for writing a reply, but your answer doesn't add much more than what my answer already stated.

Comment: Oh sorry, i don't see your answer from my mobile. Regards

Comment: Fair enough. I will upvote your answer now in good will. :) Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

I have obviously been writing to much Java code lately. Drop the parentheses when calling the function and everything works flawlessly:

```
function greet {
  echo "Hello, $1"
}

VAR=$(greet "John Doe")
```